# How can I design around this restriction on concepts and incomplete types?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, incomplete-type

I have something like this:

```
template <typename T>
requires ::std::movable<T> || ::std::copyable<T> || ::std::is_void_v<T>
class ValueWrapper
{
   // various functions to do stuff with value
};

class Value {
 public:
    Value(Value const &) = delete;
    Value &operator =(Value const &) = delete;
    Value(Value &&other) noexcept : x_{other.x_} { other.x_ = -1; }
    Value &operator =(Value &&other) {
        Value tmp{::std::move(other)};
        x_ = tmp.x_;
        tmp.x_ = -1;
        return *this;
    }

ValueWrapper<Value> do_something() const;  // Generates error related to incomplete type. :-(

 private:
    int x_;
};
```

It, of course, doesn't work because at the time the compiler sees the `do_something` declaration, `Value` is an incomplete type, and it's not possible to test an incompete type for being movable or copyable, and it isn't void.

How should I design around this?

I could change ValueWrapper so the individual member functions required things instead of having the class require something of the template parameter. But, this seems obtuse, since the intent of the class is to wrap movable or copyable things. I could move `do_something` out of the `Value` class and make it a free function. But this seems overly constraining and may not be a sensible thing to do for the methods of any `Value` class.

Are there any other design choices here that don't have these shortcomings?

In the particular, non-abstracted case that currently concerns me, `ValueWrapper` happens to be something like Boost `expected`, and so is being used to signal either an error or value return.

**Edit:** My favorite answer so far involves using `auto`, and requires that the function definition appear inline in order to work. If you want the function definition to *not* be inline, you can do this bunch of gymnastics. But, it's really weird.

```
#include <concepts>
#include <utility>


template <typename T>
requires ::std::movable<T> || ::std::copyable<T> || ::std::is_void_v<T>
class ValueWrapper
{
   // various functions to do stuff with value
};

namespace priv_ {
    // We can forward declare a class without its member functions.
    // But we can't forward declare a function without being able to
    // fully name all of its types.
    class Silly;
}

class Value {
 public:
    Value() : x_{-1} { }
    Value(Value const &) = delete;
    Value &operator =(Value const &) = delete;
    Value(Value &&other) noexcept : x_{other.x_} { other.x_ = -1; }
    Value &operator =(Value &&other) {
        Value tmp{::std::move(other)};
        x_ = tmp.x_;
        tmp.x_ = -1;
        return *this;
    }

    // inline here is basically documenting that we intend to give an
    // inline definition later. We might want to say what the actual
    // return type is too.
    auto inline do_something() const;

 private:
    int x_;

    // And we can friend a forward declared class so all of its member
    // functions are basically member functions of this class (and
    // hence have unrestricted access to all member functions and
    // variables).
    friend class priv_::Silly;
};

namespace priv_ {
    class Silly {
     public:
        // And finally, now that the Value type is 'complete', we can
        // use it as a parameter to the `ValueWrapper` template type.
        static ValueWrapper<Value> p_do_something(Value const &v);
    };
}

auto inline Value::do_something() const
{
    // And now that the declaration for `p_do_something` has been
    // seen, we can call it.
    return priv_::Silly::p_do_something(*this);
}

ValueWrapper<Value> foo()
{
    Value v;
    return v.do_something();
}
```

Comment: Do you want `do_something()` to chain, or is it ok if it returns a base class with most/all the same functionality?

Comment: @MooingDuck - What do you mean by 'chain'?

Comment: `a.doSomething().doSomething().doSomething()`. This is most common witih `operator+`

Comment: Or `.result()` when using an `expected`-like type. Yeah, chaining is important.

Comment: Unrelated: `copyable` implies `movable`, so `|| copyable<T>` is superfluous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type is complete within a member function definition, so we can use a deduced return type:

```cpp
auto do_something() const {
    return ValueWrapper<Value>();
}
```

Comment: That looks really promising.

Comment: I tested this out. It's nearly the perfect solution. Avoids almost all of the downsides and only introduces a tiny downside of it's own that can easily be solved with a comment or having a very simple and obvious function body specified inline.

There is one major downside though. If the function is at all complex and needs to be in its own `.cpp` file, this won't work. There are a few ways around that. For one, you can have a free function in a `priv_` namespace that you call to do all the work, so the interface can still have the function show up as a member function.

Comment: Further clarification. The `priv_` trick requires some interesting gymnastics involving declaring the function inline in the class body, then defining it later, outside the class body, after the declaration in the `priv_` namespace is seen. And it can't be a friend, because declaring it as a friend requires a forward declaration which introduces the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

What about transforming `do_something ()` in a template method with a default type?

I mean something as

```
template <typename U = Value>
ValueWrapper<U> do_something() const;
```

or also

```
template <int..., typename U = Value>
ValueWrapper<U> do_something() const;
```

if you want to avoid that `do_something()` can be called explicating a type.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think of that.